# Modx Wayfinder different context menu only shown after refresh

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks

I'm trying to display the main menu from other context using Wayfinder. I have the following call:

```
[[!Wayfinder@MainMenu? &startId=`0` &contexts=`web` &scheme=`full`]]
```

The problem is that the first time the page is visited, no menu is displayed. After a refresh it shows up. This happens from time to time.

I'm guessing it's some kind of cache problem but I can't figure out why it doesn't show the first time round.

Setting cacheResults to true or false doesn't seem to affect the issue.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer might come in late but you should try manually deleting the contents of core > cache via ftp or ssh. That usually does the trick when I have issues like that.